# Relativistic-speed cameras

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation, camera

I am asking on behalf of someone else. Here is their question:

Two cameras, each recording video at 500 trillion fps, are speeding toward each other at $0.6c$, on a direct collision course. When the cameras collide, they eject their data drives so it can be collected and reviewed.

However, this means that one camera will never capture the other camera, as it is moving at $1.2c$ relative to the camera. So would this be true, and if not, why?

---

My note: I am thinking that each camera will be able to see the other camera, due to time dilation and other relativistic effects.

Answer (score 3):

in special relativity,  [you have to use the relativistic velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula), to transfer to the observed velocity in the frame of one of the cameras:

$$v = \frac{v_{1} + v_{2}}{1 + \frac{v_{1}v_{2}}{c^{2}}}$$

so, your camera would observe the other camera moving at:

$$v = \frac{0.6c + 0.6c}{1 + 0.36} = 0.882 c$$

Answer (score 3):

$$0.6c + 0.6c \ne 1.2c$$

It's the classical point of view that speeds simply add. For common speeds in our lives it is a very good approximation, but for such high speeds is necessary to use the **exact** (“relativistic”) formula

$$\frac{u + v}{\color{red}{1 + \frac{uv}{c^2}}}.$$

As you may see, the denominator $\color{red}{1 + \frac{uv}{c^2}}$ is for low speeds $u, v$ almost $1$ because $c^2$ is an incredibly large number, so the result $(u+v)$ is a very good approximation.

But in your case of very high speeds, $u = v = 0.6c,$ the denominator $\color{red}{1 + \frac{uv}{c^2}}$ makes a difference, because its value is $\color{red}{1.36}$; instead of their sum you will obtain

$$\frac{0.6c + 0.6c}{1 + \frac{0.6c\cdot 0.6c}{c^2}} = \frac{1.2c}{1 + \frac{0.36c^2}{c^2}} = \frac{1.2c}{1 + 0.36} = \frac{1.2c}{\color{red}{1.36}} \approx 0.88c $$

Comment: now we gotta do colored formulas?

Answer (score 2):

While @JerrySchirmer and @MarianD gave good answers, 
here's a spacetime diagram that explains why it is $(15/17)c\approx 0.88c$.

(The rotated graph paper helps us visualize the ticks along observer worldlines [timelines] and spacelines. The "light-clock diamonds" (traced out by rays in a light-clock) have equal areas, as required by the Lorentz transformation.)

In the Lab Frame (along LOZ), before the collision at event Z

- the frontward-bound camera (along BZ) has velocity $\displaystyle\frac{BO}{OZ}c=\frac{6}{10}c$,
  using distant-event B and local-event O that LOZ says are simultaneous.

  Thinking vectorially, $\vec {BZ}=\vec{BO} + \vec{OZ}$.
- the rearward-bound camera (along AZ) has velocity $\displaystyle\frac{AO}{OZ}c=\frac{-6}{10}c$,
  using distant-event A and local event O that LOZ says are simultaneous.

  Thinking vectorially, $\vec {AZ}=\vec{AO} + \vec{OZ}$.

In the rearward-bound camera frame (along AZ), before the collision at event Z

- the lab frame (along LOZ) has velocity $\displaystyle\frac{PN}{NZ}c=\frac{6}{10}c$,

  using distant-event P and local-event N that AZ says are simultaneous.

  Thinking vectorially, $\vec {PZ}=\vec{PN} + \vec{NZ}$.
- the frontward -bound camera frame (along BZ) has velocity $\displaystyle\frac{BM}{MZ}c=\frac{15}{17}c\approx 0.88c$,

  using distant-event B and  local-event M  that AZ says are simultaneous.

  Thinking vectorially, $\vec {BZ}=\vec{BM} + \vec{MZ}$.

The key is that velocity-measurements (say, of BZ) by an observer (like AZ) requires
a purely-spatial "rise" (like BM) [along simultaneous events] and a purely-temporal "run" (like MZ) [along same-place events] according to that observer.

[image: robphy-RRGP-VelocityComposition]

[image: robphy-RRGP-VelocityComposition-AZframe]

You can use the rotated graph paper gridlines to draw in what each observer “sees” (by receiving light signals on their worldlines that were broadcast by other observers... that is, “read the clock readings sent from distant worldlines”).
The visual comparison of the received distant-clock timestamps with the local-clock timestamps involves the Doppler factor $k=\sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}$. (For $v=(3/5)c$, we have $k=2$, which is why those diamonds are stretched by a factor of 2 in the forward direction and shrunk by 2 in the other. For $v=(15/17)c$, we have $k=4$.)
[$k$ is an eigenvalue of the Lorentz boost transformation.]

Incidentally, using rapidity, 
$(15/17)=\tanh(\mbox{arctanh}(\frac{3}{5})+\mbox{arctanh}(\frac{3}{5}))$ and 
$2=\exp( \mbox{arctanh}(\frac{3}{5}))$ and 
$4=\exp(  \mbox{arctanh}(\frac{3}{5}) + \mbox{arctanh}(\frac{3}{5}) )$.

When the velocities yield rational values for $k$, the arithmetic involves simple fractions since rational $k$'s are associated with Pythagorean triples. That's why $v=(3/5)c$ is arithmetically simpler than $v=(1/2)c$.